# Variable distances between bars on ggplot bar plot

Tags: r

I have the following bar plot created using R ggplot. How do I dynamically update the distances between the bars on the plot using the 'distance' column of the same data frame.

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(name = c("A","B","C","D","E"),
           value = c(34,45,23,45,75),
           distance = c(3,4,1,2,5)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean "width" of each bar? or gap between each bar?

Comment: @DarrenTsai the gap between bars